# Does Central Authentication Service has any provision for limiting access for user per service?

Tags: python, django, single-sign-on, cas

I have been working on a Django SSO solution that uses django-mama-cas library for CAS. However the library, provides a setting to control what all services are supported.

There is no provision to do that in the database by controlling what each user can or cannot access.

If I fork this library and add a solution that maintains which user has access to certain services via the db, will it go against the standard CAS spec ?

If not, Is there something better than CAS that has this feature in it's standard ?

I know this question seems subjective, but please consider that I am asking for Yes/No as answers so it should not go against SO's guidelines.
I have also searched a lot about other solutions before coming here.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Yes, you can do it.

Check current implementation of CAS server, there is role based access control feature. More details can be found on CAS git https://github.com/Jasig/cas/issues/798.